# JQuery UI Selectable CSS Styling

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have successfully implemented JQuery UI Selectable, but need the selected items to have a specific style. I know that I can use this:

```
.ui-selected{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

but really I want to add the class .selected to the selected items (actually li tags).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The selector above, and I'm now trying to search through the UI files to find a reference to .ui-selected...

Comment: $('.ui-selected').addClass('selected');  ?

Comment: How would I integrate this with the main function, how do I make the stop: event work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I ended up using this:

```
$(".selectableTileList").selectable({
              stop: function( event, ui ) {
                //Stop function
                $('.ui-selected').addClass('selected');
              },
              start: function( event, ui ) {
                  $('.ui-selected').removeClass('selected');
              },
              selecting: function( event, ui ) {$('.ui-selected').addClass('selected');}
            });
```

Thanks to dwhite.me for his comment